# Ubuntu Nginx after blocking ip address, still showing up in logs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, brute-force-attacks

I have a server that keeps trying to brute force hack via xml-rpc post on a wordpress site. I've blocked the ip address in nginx.conf and noticed that I kept getting these errors in the log file, and since they are brute force, this is just a very, very slow DDOS (because they are causing log files to take space).

> [error] 30912#0: *4600 access forbidden by rule, client:

I've searched here for log file changes but it looks like it's all or nothing on 403 errors and that wouldn't help me (wouldn't see any others).

To combat this, I've tried blocking by firewall (using UFW wrapper around firewall tables) and added an entry on that shows as this in status:

> Anywhere    DENY        XXX.XXX.X.XXX (redacted)

However, even after enabling the firewall rules, and checking to make sure they are running, when tailing the log file I still the same error entries 403 errors writing over and over again.

Any thoughts on how to make this hacker go away without filling up the log file? It's a virtual 14.04 LTS server.

Edit: Would using `limit_req` make any difference on this at all? 
Edit Two: Here's UFW status, he's brute forcing a POST to the site. He's successfully blocked, but shouldn't the firewall prevent him from getting to nginx in the first place?

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
2222/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        XXX.XXX.X.XXX
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2222/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: So you have a server that's attempting a brute force attack, or a server on the internet is brute force attacking you? Please post your nginx configuration. Sounds like you've set up your firewall wrong if they can still get to Nginx. You can also turn off logging for a specific resource using a location block specific to that resource. Or put CloudFlare free in front of the website and block it before it reaches your server.

Comment: edited to show my firewall rules.

Comment: Move you DENY rule above your ALLOW rule for port 80. SSH probably shouldn't be open to anywhere, but be careful not to lock yourself out if you have a dynamic IP.

Comment: that did it, thank you! I have a dynamic ip, but have other rules for SSH limiting failed attempts, etc.

Comment: Great I'll answer so this gets marked as answers so others don't have to bother reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move you DENY rule above your ALLOW rule for port 80 - they're run in order.

SSH probably shouldn't be open to anywhere, but be careful not to lock yourself out if you have a dynamic IP.

Consider a CDN like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which offers protection against many threats, a firewall, etc, with free and paid plans.

Answer (score 2):

Place a rule on top of everything using the  `insert` option.

Step 1- Get the rule number:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

Step 2- Place this rule at the desired number - in this case 1, so that it overrides other Allows

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from xx.xxx.xx.xx
```